# Compiler error CS1061 when trying to access the ActiveCell from worksheet in my VSTO excel application

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins

Compiler error CS1061 when trying to programmatically get the top and left positions of ActiveCell in Excel VSTO using C#

```
//using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
//Create a reference to the active Excel worksheet 
Worksheet activeWorksheet = (Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;

//Get the top and left position of the active cell
int topPosition = activeWorksheet.ActiveCell.Top;
int leftPosition = activeWorksheet.ActiveCell.Left;
```

The compiler complains about the activeCell, that the worksheet has no definition and the value is not available. has anyone found a solution to that issue? I did test my code when making sure there is an active cell but still no use.

[image: The error message is as follows:]

CS1061: 'Worksheet' does not contain a definition for 'ActiveCell' and no accessible extension method 'ActiveCell' accepting a first argument of type 'Worksheet' could be found (are you missing using a directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Rather than trying to summarise compiler errors, please always copy/paste the *exact* error message into your post.

Comment: The error code is mentioned in the title of the question. And here is a reference for what the error code means: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061 I hope you find that Helpful.

Comment: Not the *code* - the *exact error message*. Hint: there's more information in the actual error message than just in the reference documentation, because there's contextual information. I don't know why you think that arguing the information I've asked for isn't helpful is a better option than *editing the question to provide the requested information*.

Comment: Ok I will recreate the error and add it to the question as well.

Comment: Okay, that's better - although a screenshot of code or an error message isn't as useful as putting the text *as text* in the question. I'd also suggest changing the title of your post - as the error message makes clear that the error isn't really when trying to get the top/left positions from the ActiveCell - it's when trying to get the ActiveCell itself (from a Worksheet in this case). That's why the full text of the error message is really important - it makes it clearer where the actual problem is.

Comment: Thank you for the good feedback to help improve the understanding and visibility of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for pointing out. Defenitely there was a lot of confusion around that from other articles and answers.

Here I post an answer after I got my code finally working:

```
//Create a reference to the active Cell in the worksheet
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range activeCell = this.Application.ActiveCell;
    if(activeCell  != null)
    {
        //Test that the value of the active cell is showing in a messagebox
        MessageBox.Show(activeCell.Value2);
        //Get the top and left position of the active cell
        double top = (double)activeCell.Top;
        double left = (double)activeCell.Left;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveCell` is no property of `Worksheet` objects.

It is a property of the `Application` object.
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.activecell?view=excel-pia)